# Trying to publish a .net core project, getting a "build has been canceled" message

Tags: visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I have a .net core project I am trying to publish. It build just fine, but I can't publish it. In the output, I simply get "Build had been canceled". Setting build logging to verbose doesn't yield any more information.

Comment: Can you paste the output here?

Comment: That's all I get in the output. Just "build has been cancelled"